# Help showing that the Internal Rate of Return is a quasi-concave function

Tags: convex-analysis, finance

I'm having some trouble understanding why if the rate of return were any  less than the minimum rate of return that would make the PV (Present Value) of the cashflow stream 0, the cash flow stream would be non-negative.

[image: Stephen Boyd, 2008, Convex Opt, Lecture 4]

The way I tried to understand it is that if you have a cash flow, a lower r would mean it gets discounted less. However, both positive and negative cash flows get discounted less, which is what confuses me. How can we conclude for certain that the PV of the cash flow stream with lower r than IRR(x) will be $\geq 0$?

Comment: Is the claim here that $IRR(x)$ is a quasi-concave function of $x$, or that $ \{r \ge 0 : PV(x,r) = 0\}$ is a convex set? Those are different things, since one is a set of $x$'s and the other is a set of $r$'s.

Comment: Only the initital cashflow is negative, which is not discounted. And if R=IRR(x) we have an equality. $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n (1+r)^{-i} x_i=0$. If R<IRR(x) then $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n (1+r)^{-i} x_i>0$. Et vice versa.